# hdfs client program using private ip address of the datanode that is running on Amazon EC2

Tags: c++, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs

All,

I am following the followings to setup a hadoop single-node cluster on Amazon EC2. Both the namenode and the datanode run on one Amazon EC2 instance.

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/
http://www.slideshare.net/benjaminwootton/configuring-your-first-hadoop-cluster-on-ec2

I have a hdfs client program in C++ and it doesn't run runs on the EC2 instance.

When my client programe tries to write the data into the cluster, I got the following exception,

```
2014-02-13 14:37:01,027 INFO hdfs.DFSClient(DFSOutputStream.java:createBlockOutputStream(1175)) - Exception in createBlockOutputStream
org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=/10.168.15.63:50010]
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:532)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:13
```

The file is created on the hdfs but empty. The exception seems to say that it can't create data block on the datanode because of using the private ip address (10.168.15.63:50010) instead of the public one (either ec2-54-xxx-xxx-233.us-xxx-1.compute.amazonaws.com or 54.xxx.xxx.233). I don't have a fixed ip address(i.e. elastic ip address).

Here is how I define the datanode address in hdfs-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>ec2-54-xxx-xxx-233.us-xxx-1.compute.amazonaws.com:50010</value>
    <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map and reduce task.
    </description>
</property>
```

What else need to be configured so that the remote client can access the Hadoop cluster on EC2?

Thank you in advance for the help!